# How to interpolate in Pandas using only previous values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([ [1,5],[1,6],[1,np.nan],[2,np.nan],[2,8],[2,4],[2,np.nan],[2,10],[3,np.nan]]),columns=['id','value'])`

```
  id   value
0  1    5
1  1    6
2  1    NaN
3  2    NaN
4  2    8
5  2    4
6  2    NaN
7  2    10
8  3    NaN
```

This is my expected output:

```
  id   value
0  1    5
1  1    6
2  1    7
3  2    NaN
4  2    8
5  2    4
6  2    2
7  2    10
8  3    NaN
```

This is my current output using this code:

`df.value.interpolate(method="krogh")`

```
0     5.000000
1     6.000000
2     9.071429
3    10.171429
4     8.000000
5     4.000000
6     2.357143
7    10.000000
8    36.600000
```

Basically, I want to do two important things here:

**Groupby ID** then **Interpolate using only above values not below row values**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
df["value_interp"]=df.value.combine_first(df.groupby("id")["value"].apply(lambda y: y.expanding().apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method="krogh").to_numpy()[-1], raw=False)))
```

Outputs:

```py
    id  value  value_interp
0  1.0    5.0           5.0
1  1.0    6.0           6.0
2  1.0    NaN           7.0
3  2.0    NaN           NaN
4  2.0    8.0           8.0
5  2.0    4.0           4.0
6  2.0    NaN           0.0
7  2.0   10.0          10.0
8  3.0    NaN           NaN
```

(It interpolates based only on the previous values within the group - hence index `6` will return `0` not `2`)

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `id` and then loop over groups to make interpolations. For `id = 2` interpolation will not give you value `2`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([ [1,5],[1,6],[1,np.nan],[2,np.nan],[2,8],[2,4],[2,np.nan],[2,10],[3,np.nan]]),columns=['id','value'])

data = []
for name, group in df.groupby('id'):
    group_interpolation = group.interpolate(method='krogh', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
    data.append(group_interpolation)

df = (pd.concat(data)).round(1)
```

**Output:**

```
    id  value
0  1.0    5.0
1  1.0    6.0
2  1.0    7.0
3  2.0    NaN
4  2.0    8.0
5  2.0    4.0
6  2.0    4.7
7  2.0   10.0
8  3.0    NaN
```

Comment: The idea wasn't just interpolate, but extrapolate using previous rows only...

Answer (score 0):

Current [pandas.Series.interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) does not support what you want so to achieve your goal you need to do 2 `grouby's` that will account for your desire to use only previous rows. The idea is as follows: to combine into one group only missing value (!!!) and previous rows (it might have limitations if you have several missing values in a row, but it serves well for your toy example)

Suppose we have a df:

```
print(df)
   ID  Value
0   1    5.0
1   1    6.0
2   1    NaN
3   2    NaN
4   2    8.0
5   2    4.0
6   2    NaN
7   2   10.0
8   3    NaN
```

Then we will combine any missing values within a group with previous rows:

```
df["extrapolate"] = df.groupby("ID")["Value"].apply(lambda grp: grp.isnull().cumsum().shift().bfill())
print(df)
   ID  Value  extrapolate
0   1    5.0          0.0
1   1    6.0          0.0
2   1    NaN          0.0
3   2    NaN          1.0
4   2    8.0          1.0
5   2    4.0          1.0
6   2    NaN          1.0
7   2   10.0          2.0
8   3    NaN          NaN
```

You may see, that when grouped by `["ID","extrapolate"]` the missing value will fall into the same group as nonnull values of previous rows.

Now we are ready to do extrapolation (with `spline` of `order=1`):

```
df.groupby(["ID","extrapolate"], as_index=False).apply(lambda grp:grp.interpolate(method="spline",order=1)).drop("extrapolate", axis=1)
    ID  Value
0  1.0    5.0
1  1.0    6.0
2  1.0    7.0
3  2.0    NaN
4  2.0    8.0
5  2.0    4.0
6  2.0    0.0
7  2.0   10.0
8  NaN    NaN
```

Hope this helps.